# Is Factor Analysis what I am looking for?

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis

I have a calls dataset with ~20 variables and I'm trying to determine what combination of variables lead to a "Win" or a "Loss". For example, when variable A is high and variable B is high, that leads to wins. Is this factor analysis?